# How to tell the AVERAGE function to avoid non numerical values

Tags: vba

I've got a worksheet that looks something like this

[image]

and what I want to do is average the values on each column using vba.

If I use the =AVERAGE() formula, that works fine and it ignores the N/A in the columns. But I need to do this with vba.

If I try to do something like

```
Sub test()

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C17").Value = WorksheetFunction.Average("C2:C14")

End Sub
```

Then I get a message saying "Unable to get the Average property of the WorksheetFunction class"

Is there any way I can tell my code to avoid the "N/A" when it calculates the averages so I don't get this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `Average` doesn't take a string input, use

```
WorksheetFunction.Average(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:C14"))
```

rather than just `WorksheetFunction.Average("C2:C14")`